# Use an extra thread and return back to the starter thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

**Note :**
Although in some similar cases **BackgroundWorker** is recommended
I prefer to do this job without it, cause this way I could make more generic code
that could be used across my applications, and it will use my naming conventions.

**What I want :**
    Show my arraylist inside MyListBox via ***ShowResult(...)*** Method

**What do you suggest as a best practice in this case**

Also maybe I have to move the Focus Method right ater the thread.Start method, which I don't know

**Sample code**

### btnPress Method :

```
        SetStatus(" Openning & Initializing the File");
        ThreadStart threadStart = new ThreadStart(HeavyProcess);
        threadProcess = new Thread(threadStart);
        threadProcess.Start();
```

### HeavyProcess Method

```
    public void HeavyProcess()
    {
        SetStatus("Thread Started!");


        // Filling an ArrayList arrHealth ....            

        ShowResult(...);
        // Filling the ListBox with the ArrayList
        // At this time I want to be sure that the extra thread be finished and it 
        // returned to the GUI thread
```

**The Cross-Thread Solution of mine :**

```
public delegate void SetStatusDelegate(string text);

public void SetStatus(string stStatus)
{
    if (statLLS.InvokeRequired)
        statLLS.Invoke(new SetStatusDelegate(SetStatus),stStatus);
    else
        statLLS.Text = stStatus;
}
```

**-- Edit --**

**Path1 :**

The same as above

This will cause an error :
Invalid Operation ...
Cross-thread operation not valid ...
When I want to access the ListBox and put the Arraylist result in it
It shows that it's still in the extra thread
how can I leave this "ShowResult(...); " for the main thread

**Path2 :**

```
        threadProcess.Start();                    
        ShowResult(...); 
        // Filling the ListBox with the ArrayList
        // the Watch shows that ArrayList is null
```

this will cause nothing !

Comment: I think now the problem could be better found ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in calling `MyListBox.Focus()` in the background thread. You can't do that with a Windows Forms app -- you must leave GUI handling to the main GUI thread. A more typical approach would be to poll or wait for the background thread to complete and then do the GUI stuff in the main thread. The point of a BackgroundWorker is that it makes this easy by providing things like the RunWorkerCompleted event to actively notify you when the thread is done.

Windows Forms does provide a specific mechanism for this kind of thing, though, with the `Windows.Forms.Timer` (NOT `System.Timers.Timer`). GUI actions performed by the event handlers attached to the `Tick` event, even though originating from a separate thread, will work.

Basically, the format is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {

    private Thread threadProcess;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer heavyProcessTimer = new Timer();

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        heavyProcessTimer.Interval = 50; // or whatever
        heavyProcessTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(heavyProcessTimer_Tick);
    }

    void heavyProcessTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!threadProcess.IsAlive) {
            heavyProcessTimer.Stop();
            MyListBox.Focus();    
            ShowResult(...);
        }
    }

    private void btnPress(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        SetStatus(" Openning & Initializing the File"); 
        ThreadStart threadStart = new ThreadStart(HeavyProcess); 
        threadProcess = new Thread(threadStart); 
        threadProcess.Start();
        heavyProcessTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was for years away from win programming, in 1.1 I could remember we could do such an activity with controls, maybe I'm wrong anyway, but also in the code above any access to the listbox will case a thread-safety error. because of that I thought It's still in the extra thread, what also I want to know is about my arraylist, thanks

Comment: @Sypress What about the `ArrayList`? Also, is there a reason you're not using a `List<T>` instead of an `ArrayList`?

Comment: No there isn't any special reason, cause I was accustomed to it :D

Comment: +1, please review the problem I edited the whole part. I dont know where and how should I put and use "ShowResults" method, thanks

Comment: @Sypress - Note that in my code, `ShowResult` is called in the `Tick` event handler _after_ the HeavyProcess thread is complete.

Comment: What about my code that there will be no extra event and timers , should I just use your conditional statement right after "threadProcess.Start();" line ? (Path 2 )

Comment: @Sypress - It's not _possible_ without "extra" event and timers. If you want to know when a thread is done, you have to check for it. _Something_ has to trigger that check on a regular basis.

Comment: also maybe you want to say that this way I'm forced to use a timer to check and find when the second thread is finished ? if so I could be sure that I should change my pattern, I thought after the second thread finished I could execute a part of my code simply .

Comment: hmmm, I didn't know that, So which pattern do you think could be suit my situation the best, maybe it wouldn't be a good idea, I could make listbox edits also thread-safe but I read that maybe that shouldn't be the best idea,is it ?

Comment: I posted my second previous comment before having got your last comment, Doesn't it have any performance draw-back ? Isn't it make the whole process of making an arrayList or as you said a generic list twice bigger in case of time ?

Comment: Also glad that you passed the 1k ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure you are in the UI thread, just `Invoke` the code you want to run there (that's the very reason `Invoke` exists -- see also `BeginInvoke`).

This would probably not be the best solution (although there are too many possibilities to reach a verdict), but it would certainly work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice, What about my ArrayList Can I fill it via the extra thread and after comming back work with it's data ? or should I pass it as a parameter between anything ?

Comment: @Sypress: You can write it in one thread and read it in another, no issue there. Just be careful that you don't read *and* write at the same time.

Comment: +1, please review the problem I edited the whole part. I dont know where and how should I put and use "ShowResults" method, thanks